# How to know if an instance of the App is running or not

Tags: android

Is there any way to periodically check if my App is not running? and if it is not running, how to turn it on automatically?

The idea is, we have an App connected to a server and we want the user to be always connected. 
our idea to solve this is issue, is to create a 'Service' that always checks every N seconds if the the user is logged-in or not, if the user is logged-out, the App should launch automatically.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: ActivityManager will give you the list of all the running applications.

**activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()**

You can use alarmManager to get the list of runningApplications periodically and find if your application is in the list or not.

Comment: Why would you want to keep the app always running? This will really drain the battery and use a lot user's data in order to keep the communication with the server? One more thing to note here is that Android O adds a lot of restrictions for the background processes, so you might want to search for an alternative.

Comment: You can check status of your app by exchanging packets client <--> server. What yo mean by `run automaticall without interaction from the user` running in background ? Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: thanks for the advise, but what do you mean by the "added restrictions to Android O", do you mean that these restrictions will facilitate working with the background processes or it is more complex

Comment: @SAZ i would like to change the question by providing some more info, should edit it or delete it?

Comment: Android O makes it harder to work with background processes because they added a lot of restrictions. A complete list of what is changed can be found here https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html